# Интеграция существующего testNG фреймворка с тестами java+cucumber

Tags: java, maven, test-automation, testng, cucumber

У меня есть:
cucumber.feature
stepDefinition.java

В такой структуре при ране cucumber.feature ищется нужный given, then и прочее в структуре проекта и выполняется сценарий.

Теперь я хочу прикрутить настроенный ранее TestNG фреймворк (testng.xml с параметрами для precinditions, и сами методы под @BeforeTest). Я создаю runner.java, который наследую согласно официальному мануалу от AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.
Потом я создаю testng.xml где прописываю класс runner.java и в общем-то все работает.

Только вот как мне заставить выполнять все @BeforeTest от TestNG если он сразу запускает класс кукумбера и реагирует только на @Before аннотации кукумбера, но не выполняет ни одного своего precondition?
Я конечно могу запихнуть в кукумберовские @Before все что раньше было в @BeforeTest у testNG но там же был еще  @Parameters и их получается надо копипастить внутрь каждого метода @Before? Какой тогда смысл в TestNG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ, на самом деле, был на поверхности.
Аннотации TestNG выполняются в случае если их поместить внутрь runner.java. XML при запуске идет в указанный runner cucumber тестов и, при создании данного класса  мониторит все аннотации testNG (в том числе параметризованные),  выполняет их, после чего уже лезет в указанные features и ищет нужные для выполнений stepdefs, аннотации внутри которых уже должны быть в cucumber-style, то есть @Before, @After и так далее.
Пример:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="TestNG Suite" parallel="tests">
<test name = "Test1">
    <classes>
        <class name="runner"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
<!--##############################-->
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/features/epic.feature"}
)

public class runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

@BeforeSuite
public void beforeSuite() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("TestNG @Before annotate");
}}
///////////////////////////////////
Feature: epic feature

@authorization
Scenario: i want to test negative and positive authorization cases

Given i push Login button
#...
###################################
public class stepDefs {
@Before
public void hello_world(){
   System.out.println("Button pushed");
}

@Given("^i push Login button$")
public void push_login() {
    System.out.println("Button pushed");
}}
```